# Use ofstream::open on ostream parameter

Tags: c++, ostream

I have a function to generate a report:

```
void generate_structure_report(const Factory &factory, std::ostream &outputloc)
```

The project requirements are that I must be able to print those to `std::cout` or a `txt file`, that's why I pass the parameter as a `std::ostream&`.

The problem is - if `std::ostream &outputloc` is a file (`std::ofstream`) I must `open()` and `close()` it appropriately. What command should I use to differentiate those two output locations?

Comment: Don't `open()` or `close()` it. Why would you need to?

Comment: It's up to the *caller* to possibly use a file-stream and make sure it's open. [Separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and all that.